# Generate truth table in MatLab

Tags: matlab, coding-efficiency

I want to create a truth table in MatLab with i columns and i<sup>2</sup> rows.  For example, if i=2, then

```
T = 
[0  0] 
[1  0] 
[0  1] 
[1  1]
```

Code to do this has already been created [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30008-function-to-generate-truth-table-condition-vectors)

This is part of a larger project, which requires i large.  Efficiency is a concern.  Is there more efficient code to create a truth table?  Does MatLab have a built in function to do this?

Edit: Sorry about the formatting!

Comment: unfortunately $$ for math blocks doesn't work over here. Usually code blocks are encased in line with backticks and you can do larger blocks with the code button (it has {}).

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still having trouble formatting the matrix.

Comment: @scrappedcola Or you can highlight the code block and hit `ctrl-k`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ndgrid is very much your friend here:

```
function t = truthTable(n)
dims = repmat({[false, true]}, 1, n);
[grids{1:n}] = ndgrid(dims{:});
grids = cellfun(@(g)g(:), grids, 'UniformOutput',false);
t = [grids{:}];
```

First you need to create grids for the number of dimensions in your truth table. Once you have those you can columnize them to get the column vectors you need and you can horizontally concatenate those column vectors to get your truth table.

I imagine the performance of this will be quite competitive.

```
>> truthTable(2)

ans =

     0     0
     1     0
     0     1
     1     1

>> truthTable(4)

ans =

     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0
     1     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     1
     0     1     0     1
     1     1     0     1
     0     0     1     1
     1     0     1     1
     0     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1

>> 
>> timeit(@() truthTable(20))

ans =

        0.030922626777
```

**EDIT:** Use reshape instead of column dereferencing for further performance improvement

```
function t = truthTable(n)
dims = repmat({[false, true]}, 1, n);
[grids{1:n}] = ndgrid(dims{:});
grids = cellfun(@(g) reshape(g,[],1), grids, 'UniformOutput',false);
t = [grids{:}];


>> timeit(@() truthTable(20))

ans =

        0.016237298777
```

Comment: Thank you.  The original code by Paul  is about twice as quick as yours.  (sec= 0.2796  versus sec =  0.5771 when n = 20).

Comment: what release are you using? Using R2015b my method is an order of magnitude faster (n=20). Updated answer to show.

Comment: It looks like Pauls is also faster in R2015b, but still slower than using ndgrid (about 0.157037 sec)

Comment: Ah! I was using an older version of Matlab.  Your solution is the fastest out of the three on R2015b.  @n=25, speed is s=10.2, 11.5, 1.8   (resp.  Paul, beaker, yours).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
n=2;
d=[0:2^n-1].';

T=dec2bin(d,n)

T =

00
01
10
11
```

`dec2bin` will give you a character array, which you can convert to logical, if needed. There's also `de2bi` that gives you a numeric array directly, but you need a newer version of Matlab and the ordering of the bits is reversed.

---

Here's [Luis Mendo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) speedup, which replicates `dec2bin` (`n` and `d` are as above):

```
T=rem(floor(d*pow2(1-n:0)),2);
```

Comment: I think you need to change the `d` line into `d=[0:2^n-1].';` Apart from that, nice answer!

Comment: Also, `dec2bin` has a lot of overhead (checking variable types etc). You can speed up using `T=rem(floor(d*pow2(1-n:0)),2);`, which is what `dec2bin` actually does, without all that checking @MattT

Comment: @LuisMendo Of course you're right... got my terms backwards.

Comment: This brings up an interesting point, that `n` cannot be *too* large, in fact it must be less than 31, or you start running out of index range.

Comment: Not to mention memory. For `n = 30` you'd be trying to generate a 30GB matrix.

Comment: Thank you.  This is similar to the reply left in the [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30008-function-to-generate-truth-table-condition-vectors) I posted above.  After 100 tests at n=20, the code by Paul is about twice as quick as rem(floor(d*pow2(1-n:0)),2);   (sec= 0.2796 versus sec=0.5969).

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look at the linked code more carefully. I'm sure @LuisMendo will be interested as well.

Comment: @beaker Interesting indeed. Paul's FEX submission is loop based. Is that really faster?

Comment: @LuisMendo I haven't timed it yet, but his implementation only sets the 1 values, thus eliminating half of the assignments.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been dead a while, but I was wondering the same thing and found a solution I like a lot. Thought I'd share it here:

```
fullfact(ones(1, i) + 1) - 1
```